# How to force Images to be loaded all the time, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I am serving a .aspx that contains Images. I haven't figured out yet how to force ie7(6) to fetch the images all the time (e.g redirects).

So far, I've added the following tags on my .aspx page:

```
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

And still, if I click the URL Bar and hit enter or do a redirect to that same page IE won't re-fetch the images.

What am I missing?

Other Notes:

```
ISS 5
IE7 7.0.5730.13
Works on Firefox and everywhere else but IE
```

Redirect Code:

```
Response.Redirect("url...", true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might just put a unique tag on the end of your image URLs to make sure the cache isn't hit. For example

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg?<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()%>" />
```

Granted, if you're using WebForms you'll want to do it a little different, but still along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is probably overriding those settings. Go into IIS Manager and find the folder where your images are located. Right-click and select Properties. Click on the HTTP Headers tab. Check the option "Enable content expiration" and "Expire immediately".

Comment: According to this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067, IE 4/5 (assuming it hasn't changed in later versions), "Cache-Control META HTTP-EQUIV tags are ignored and have no effect in Internet Explorer versions 4 or 5. To use Cache-Control this header must be specified using HTTP headers as described in the Cache-Control section above."

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.enhanceie.com/redir/?id=httpperf for an explanation of how HTTP caching works, and how you can cache or not-cache your files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but we solve a similar problem adding these lines to the aspx.cs file, in the PageLoad Event:

```
//Turn off cache
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

It could be useful to solve your problem too

http://royriojas.blogspot.com/2009/04/dealing-with-back-button-and-secured.html

Comment: Thanks but IE still keeps caching stuff after your recommendation.. arrgh!