# asp.net Internet Explorer image cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, internet-explorer

I'm writing an asp.net app in c#.  In my program an image of a schedule grid has lines drawn on it depending on the selections from the user.  When the user selects a day, the image is redrawn to show the scheduled time"lines" for that day.  This works fine in Chrome, and Firefox, however in Internet Explorer(9) the image won't change to another day, it only displays whatever the first image was regardless of what day the user selects afterward.

I used this code on the code-behind because I thought it was caching the image, but it didn't resolve the issue.  Any pointers?

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

(A standard clean grid image is loaded, drawn on, then renamed and saved to a different local folder.  Then that new image is loaded to an image control on the screen. This happens every time the user changes days.)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the image is redrawn?  Caching should only be an issue if you have a different image with the same name.

Comment: What's the HTTP traffic saying?

Comment: The clean image is drawn on and renamed then saved, but always as the same filename.  So image "grid.jpg" is loaded, drawn on with the selected day's times, then saved as newgrid.jpg.  That newgrid.jpg image is always loaded into the image control.

Comment: Does the client access the image directly or is it some .ashx that outputs it?

Comment: Possibly IE cached the image before you set the expires headers, and still thinks it's still valid, and not requesting it again. Try cleaning IE cache manually, and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to MS's documentation on avoiding image caching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d(v=vs.71).aspx

And place this in this page_load method:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

But since you are naming the file at run time, I would just name the file differently each time (maybe using the date since it's a timeline), so that other images on the page are not also cached.

Comment: That seems like a fairly simple solution, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: I found a related solution to my problem here, in case anyone is curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983653/how-to-force-images-to-be-loaded-all-the-time-asp-net